# How to pass _OPTIONS to included premake4 scripts?

Tags: premake

I've got a main premake4.lua script:

```
solution "MySolution"

language "c++"

newoption = {
    trigger = "my-option",
    description = "This is an option"
}

include "../my_library"
```

I would like to pivot logic in the included script ( ../my_library/premake4.lua ) based on the contents of _OPTIONS:

```
if _OPTIONS["my-option"] then
    project "myStaticLibrary"
        kind "StaticLib"
else
    project "mySharedLibrary"
        kind "SharedLib"
end

files "foo.cpp"
```

How to get _OPTIONS in the scope of the included premake4 script?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything. `_OPTIONS` is a global variable and will be accessible to all of your scripts automatically. Are you seeing otherwise?

Comment: Yes, I was seeing otherwise: _OPTIONS was completely empty.  I tried overriding the **include** function to work around it but then some of the other premake4 features didn't work.  However after more work I learned that I was Doing It Wrong.  The right way was to create ReleaseDLL and DebugDLL configurations and then specify the **config=** at the **make** step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question just in case anyone else is tempted to solve things in the same way.  I was **Doing It Wrong**.  After struggling with it my final solution defined multiple **configurations**:

```
-- the main script
solution "MySolution"

    language "c++"

    configurations { "Release", "Debug", "ReleaseDLL", "DebugDLL" }

    configuration { "Release", "ReleaseDLL" }
        flags { "Optimize" }
    configuration { "Debug", "DebugDLL" }
        flags { }
        defines {"_DEBUG=1"}
    configuration {}

    include "../my_library"
```

The included script specified the **kind** according to **configuration**:

```
-- the included script
project "myStaticLibrary"

    configuration { "*" }
        kind "StaticLib"
    configuration { "*DLL" }
        kind "SharedLib"
    configuration {}

    files "foo.cpp"
```

And to to build the right targets the **config** is specified at the **make**:

```
premake4 gmake
cd gmake
make config=release
make config=debug
make config=releasedll
make config=debugdll
```